# Toggle Menu is not showing in mobile view

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, header, toggle

My toggle menu bar is not showing in mobile view. my website is `http://gtcgroups.com/` . When I decrease the window size the menu is not showing. How to fix it. I am currently using WPtouch plugin but its not showing logo of website that's why i want to do it through custom code for toggle menu.I have tried different codes but not working

```
header .menu .nav {
    display: none !important;
}
header .menu.active .nav {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: You should bring your code. so we can help you.

Comment: i have tried this one: header .menu .nav {
    display: none !important;
}
header .menu.active .nav {
    display: block !important;
}      The question is updated

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your written CSS in your custom.css

```
.header-wrap {
    height: 30px;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
replace it by
.header-wrap {
    height: 30px;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    max-with:100%
}
```